# BCP output to UTF-16 (or ANSI) in SQL Server 2012

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

In my database I have all text correct, for instance:

```
Hèllo, I äm World
```

When I write this text to a file in SQL:

```
set @command = 'bcp "select [TEXT] from [TABLE] where [ID] = ' + 
                @id queryout +' + @filename + '.html" -S ' + @instance +
                ' -c -U ' + @username + ' -P ' + @password"
exec xp_cmdshell @command, no_ouput
```

But the result looks like

```
H?llo, I ?m World
```

The issue seems to be the encoding. But I read that I cannot add the flag `-w 65001` as this is only supported on SQL Sever 2016 (we are on 2012).

How can I still get the correct output?

Comment: I suspect the real question is "How to I generate a report" and the assumption is that you need `bcp` to do it. Not quite. `bcp` is a *command-line* tool for bulk import/export, not something you call in a SQL query. It's not a generic import/export tool. That's what SSIS is for, or a reporting tool. `-c` means ANSI while your text needs Unicode (ie -w or -N if the fields use `nvarchar`). The output won't be HTML either, it will be a flat file. `-w` doesn't take parameters.

Comment: If you want to generate an HTML report, use SSRS or another reporting tool. If you want to export data in a Unicode flat file, [read the docs first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017). To export data as Unicode use `bcp "yourquery" -w`. If your text is stored in `nvarchar` fields, use `-N`. If the data is stored as `varchar` (ie ASCII) you may have to specify the codepage explicitly with `-C RAW`. You may need that if the data was added using the wrong codepage

Comment: Finally, you don't need to specify the username/passowrd. You can use Windows authentication to connect to SQL Server using the current account.